# Creating a dataframe includes my cross validation scores

Tags: python, pandas

I'm kinda beginner and stuck at some basic part of my work. I want to create a pandas dataframe showing my CV scores and std's per model. I managed to get the results I want but I feel like I did it the wrong way.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, KFold, cross_val_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression, Ridge
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score, mean_squared_error
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor, RandomForestRegressor, BaggingRegressor
import xgboost as xgb
import lightgbm as lgb

mods = [LinearRegression(),Ridge(),GradientBoostingRegressor(),
  RandomForestRegressor(),BaggingRegressor(),
  xgb.XGBRegressor(), lgb.LGBMRegressor()]
scores = []
stds = []
for mod in mods:
    score = rmsle_cv(mod)
    scores.append(score.mean())
    stds.append(score.std())
```

This is the part I'm not sure about, It's working but whenever I want to add a new model I need to edit lists twice, I wonder if there is a better way to do this(I don't wanna have another list includes model names:

```
models = ['LinearRegression','Ridge','GradientBoostingRegressor',
  'RandomForestRegressor','BaggingRegressor', 'XGBRegressor', 'LGBMRegressor']
model_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Model': models,
    'Score': scores,
    'Std': stds})
print(model_df.sort_values(by='Score', ascending=True).reset_index(drop=True))
```

Comment: From which library are you getting these models? Can you include the `import` statements?

Comment: 'from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, KFold, cross_val_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression, Ridge
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score, mean_squared_error
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor, RandomForestRegressor, BaggingRegressor
import xgboost as xgb
import lightgbm as lgb'

Comment: I think you could also be a tad more elegant with the `scores` and `stds` lists. Try list comprehensions.

Comment: @retardo: always edit the code into the question. It needs to be reproducible (MCVE), so it needs all the imports. Also it's useful to tell people this is Python and pandas ('dataframe' exists in R too).

Comment: @smci, thanks, I'm a beginner in asking questions too. Gonna get better soon I hope :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do type(model) and there is an variable `__name__` . Try something like this below, I could not get the score for your models so I used a simple r2

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression, Ridge 
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor, RandomForestRegressor, BaggingRegressor 
import xgboost as xgb 
import lightgbm as lgb
import pandas as pd

mods = [LinearRegression(),Ridge(),GradientBoostingRegressor(),
  RandomForestRegressor(),BaggingRegressor(),
  xgb.XGBRegressor(), lgb.LGBMRegressor()]

data = load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(data.data, columns=['sepal.length','sepal.width','petal.length','petal.width'])

X = df[['sepal.length','sepal.width']]
y = df['petal.width']

fitted = [mod.fit(X,y) for mod in mods]

model_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Model': [type(i).__name__ for i in fitted],
    'Score': [i.score(X,y) for i in fitted]
    })

model_df

                       Model     Score
0           LinearRegression  0.742928
1                      Ridge  0.742797
2  GradientBoostingRegressor  0.929430
3      RandomForestRegressor  0.943384
4           BaggingRegressor  0.941296
5               XGBRegressor  0.919452
6              LGBMRegressor  0.861518
```

Comment: Thank you! Adding _'Model': [type(i).__name__ for i in mods]_ worked like a charm, I wish I know this before!

Comment: you're welcome :)

Comment: Your method of getting at the model name is definitely more elegant than mine, I'll admit. I'll leave my solution up, though.

Answer (score 4):

Most of your models are from `sklearn`, so I think you might be able to do something like the following. Note very carefully that I have created a list of the functions, not their instantiations. Note that I instantiate the models at the end. Also, I don't seem to have your `xgboost` module, nor your `lightgbm` module, so I left those out. You might or might not be able to extract the right info from their `__init__` properties.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression, Ridge
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor, \
    RandomForestRegressor, BaggingRegressor

mods = [LinearRegression, Ridge, GradientBoostingRegressor,
        RandomForestRegressor, BaggingRegressor]


def extract_name_from_sklearn_model(model) -> str:
    """
    This function extracts a model's name, and assumes it has a fit
    method.
    """

    prop = '__init__'

    # Get a dict of the model's properties.
    properties = dict(vars(model).items())

    # Assume it has a fit method.
    predict_str = str(properties[prop])

    # Get whatever is after the string '<function ' and before
    # the string '.prop'. That should be the function name.
    func_name = predict_str.split('<function ')[1] \
        .split('.' + prop)[0]

    return func_name


models = [extract_name_from_sklearn_model(model) for model in mods]
print(str(models))

# Finally, you need to instantiate your classes.
mod_classes = [func() for func in mods]
```

Now you can maintain one list of models, so long as they include a `'__init__'` method from which you can extract the model's name.

I also think your lists could be more elegant. Maybe something like this:

```
score = [rmsle_cv(mod) for mod in mod_classes]
scores = [this_score.mean() for this_score in score]
stds = [this_score.std() for this_score in score]
```